# How Is ToShortDateString() determined when run?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having a lot of issues with this method. If I compile code to an executable will the method generate a date string in the format of the machine its run on or the machine its compiled on?

I compile it on a machine based in europe with a UK date format and run it on a machine based in the US what will the date format be? I have had to start generating the date string manually, but this leads to other errors as it seems that SQL server converts the date from UK format to US format automatically, so when i manually generate the string in US format it throws an exception when i run it on my laptop to test the code before committing it live.

Comment: It's always using the current culture's date-format. You can specify another with `ToString("d", culture)`, f.e. `DateTime.Now.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-US"))`. The return value of `ToShortDateString` is identical to the value returned by specifying the "d" with `ToString("d")`.

Comment: if it can be defined explicitly, it will still give me the same issues that im having with sql servers datetime field.

Comment: Why not use sql parameters for whatever you're querying? They'll do the work for you.

Comment: @Dan: What are you doing with your dates in SQL Server and when passing them in/out of it? Dates are dates: the way that they're formatted -- whether by you or SQL Server -- should be irrelevant so long as you pass them around *as dates* rather than as strings.

Comment: Note: where you build does not matter, the value is calculated at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

From [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1150);

```
public String ToShortDateString() {
       return DateTimeFormat.Format(this, "d", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

That means it uses [The `"d"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate)  of the [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings.

And from [The Short Date (`"d"`) Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate)

> The `"d"` standard format specifier represents a custom date and time
> format string that is defined by a specific culture's
> [`DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx).

That means, this method generates short date pattern of the current culture settings. That's why it is *too* normal to get different results if your current culture settings are not the same in different machines. If you wanna specify another culture, you can use it as a second parameter in a `ToString` method.

> it seems that SQL server converts the date from UK format to US format
> automatically

Based on this, I *strongly* suspect you try to save your `DateTime` values as a string to your SQL Server. **Do not do that**. Pass them as a `DateTime` *directly* to your [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just date and time values. And SQL Server saves it as a `binary`. The format concept only matter when you get it's *textual* (string) representation.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

It formats using the `CurrentCulture` of the Thread it is executed, so it is not determined at CompileTime, see this Test:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
// in germany: 20.10.2015
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
// in usa: 10/20/2015
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
```

You can bypass this by commiting the desired culture to the `ToString` method, which does not affect the CurrentCulture of your Thread:

```
// "d" is standard-format for short date pattern,
// see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/en-en/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx for further info
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("en-us")));
```

However, interacting with DBMS, I strongly recommend using the ISO Date-Pattern like so:

```
dt.ToString("O");  // 2015-10-20T13:08:53.1242403+02:00
```